# Laravel and MSSQL not UTF8 charset

Tags: character-encoding, vagrant, laravel-5.5, sqlsrv

So I have outside MSSQL database, I can connect, but  some charset are displayed as "����" symbols.

Laravel database config (I'm using Laravel version 5.5.32 + php 7.2):

```
   'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('MS_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('MS_DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('MS_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('MS_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('MS_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
```

I'm Using vagrant, to connect to MSSQL I installed drivers with command:

```
 apt install php7.2-sybase
```

MSSQL database using cp1257 encoding (Windows-1257)
(I did that query to find out it):

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

I can not make any changes to MSSQL (it's old one), but can make any on vagrant/laravel. I tried to change charsets in database.php, I tried to convert result to UTF8 , but response displayed in Laravel is always with � symbols.

Any ideas how to get proper encoding?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but I have a similar database encoding and I use $xstring = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $xstring) to convert results from database (in your case it must be "CP1257").

Comment: Tried that. Result is same. It seems that Lavarel always get result in his UTF-8, does not matter what I choose in database.php charset. ( I used mb_detect_encoding() to detect charset of result, it was always � and charset "UTF-8")